# Mongo Auth with pymongo Safe Insert

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm running Mongo 2.2.0, sharded and replicated, and I'm having a bit of weird behavior using python (pymongo 2.1.1).

Things to note:

> Users with correct privileges have been created on each database I am attempting to access.
>
> The following are connecting via a mongo router.
>
> MONGO_URI is an env variable set earlier in deployment: $MONGO_URI = "mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/DB"

I can auth, read and write just fine through the mongo shell, I can also fire up a python session and the following works just fine:

```
    >>> import pymongo
    >>> import os
    >>> c = pymongo.Connection(os.environ['MONGODB_URI'])
    >>> c.DB.COLL.insert(dict(a=2))
    >>> list(c.DB.COLL.find())
```

But when I use safe=True on insert:

```
    >>> import pymongo
    >>> import os
    >>> c = pymongo.Connection(os.environ['MONGODB_URI'])
    >>> c.DB.COLL.insert(dict(a=2), safe=True)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 312, in insert
    continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 822, in    _send_message
    return self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 759, in __check_response_to_last_error
    helpers._check_command_response(error, self.disconnect)
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 128, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % response["errmsg"])
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unauthorized
```

Am I calling something the wrong way, or might there be a bug with auth and safe somewhere? I'm inclined to believe in my own error first, but I get correct behavior if I leave safe off in the insert statement.

I have looked into these topics:

[Pymongo gives db assertion failure while trying to access remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627611/pymongo-gives-db-assertion-failure-while-trying-to-access-remote-server)
[Pymongo permissions issue for safe inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532185/pymongo-permissions-issue-for-safe-inserts)
[OperationFailure: database error when threading in MongoEngine/PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857898/operationfailure-database-error-when-threading-in-mongoengine-pymongo)

...but I haven't found an answer that doesn't require me to deactivate auth.

EDIT:
I also posted on the googlegroup and got my answer, it was a bug in pymongo. I upgraded to 2.3 and everything worked like expected.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/UlbW4942xsw

Comment: It seems possible the the getLastError call is not being sent with the appropriate priveleges.  What do the logs from the mongod say?

Comment: I've tailed the primary node logs and run the commands, watching for something. There seems to be no reactive logs, just the regular periodic things like:
    Thu Oct 18 18:19:10 [conn5627] end connection 10.29.191.31:46937 (34 connections now open)
    Thu Oct 18 18:19:10 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.29.191.31:46939 #5629 (35 connections now open)
    Thu Oct 18 18:19:10 [conn5629]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "f47f68d0c4ab0b3f", user: "__system", key: "85007f6a39f3f6fc8fe8db1b21648d99" }

Comment: I could not reproduce the error - what happens if you run [authenticate](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate) on the database before doing an insert?